# jquery mouseover while loop

Tags: jquery, html

I have this jquery function that shows a paragraph tag on hover.

The problem is that I have my paragraph inside a php while loop so there will be more p tags with the same class and therefore when I hover over one I see the text from all of them.

Is there anyway to avoid this so I only see the text for the one I'm actually hovering over even though they have the same class?

```
<div class="profit" style="height:<?php if($tinyCasePriceProfit >= 100)
    { echo 200;} else{ echo $tinyCasePriceProfit; }?>px; background-color:green; width:20px; border-radius:5px; margin-left:67%; top:31.3%;"></div>


<div class="loss" style="height:<?php if($tinyCasePriceLoss >= 100)
    { echo 200;} else{ echo $tinyCasePriceLoss; }?>px; background-color:red; width:20px; border-radius:5px; margin-left:65%; margin-top:-14px;"></div>
        <p class="lossOfProject" style="display:none; margin-left: 60%;">Tab på dette projekt er: <?php echo $moneyLostOnCase;?> Kr</p>
<p class="profitOfProject" style="display:none; margin-left: 60%;">Tjen på dette projekt er: <?php echo $casePrice;?> Kr</p>

$('.loss').mouseover(function(){
            $('.lossOfProject').fadeIn();
            });

$('.profit').mouseover(function(){
            $('.profitOfProject').fadeIn();
            });
```

Note html code is in a php while loop that makes more of the paragraph then one :)

Comment: What's the `$('.loss').height();` for? Where's the PHP/HTML?

Comment: @below9k the loss that i am targeting is a div and i needed the height i did however found another way to get i so i just forgot to delete it:-)

Comment: @Anoxy, the best way for us to visualize what you're saying is if you could provide a snippet of the markup (HTML).

Comment: @PeterKA now updated with html code! thanks! :)

Comment: So do you want both of the `p.profitOfProject` elements to be display on click? And, usually client-side rendering of your PHP is better for us to use here. Could you post that and post at least two sets so we can determine the most appropriate method to use.

Comment: @PeterKA   Okat this i what i want to achieve i have 2 divs as you can see one named profit and one named loss when i hover over loss for example i want to get the p.lossOfProject but only for the loss div i am hovering over not all the other loss divs hope you understand! :)

Comment: Ok, take a look at my answer and demo; that should set you on your way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.next()` method remembering to keep the context with `this`;

You, too, should use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`

```
$('.loss').mouseenter(function(){             
     $(this).next('.lossOfProject').fadeIn();
});
```

Here is a demo:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.loss').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $('.lossOfProject').not( $(this).next() ).hide();
    $(this).next('.lossOfProject').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
.profitOfProject, .lossOfProject {
  display:none;
}
.loss {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loss">
  LOSS ... click here
</div>
<p class="lossOfProject">Profit 1</p>
<p class="profitOfProject")Profit 2</p>
<div class="loss">
  LOSS ... click here
</div>
<p class="lossOfProject">Profit 1</p>
<p class="profitOfProject")Profit 2</p>
<div class="loss">
  LOSS ... click here
</div>
<p class="lossOfProject">Profit 1</p>
<p class="profitOfProject")Profit 2</p>
<div class="loss">
  LOSS ... click here
</div>
<p class="lossOfProject">Profit 1</p>
<p class="profitOfProject")Profit 2</p>
```

Comment: This works like a charm! thank you for your time! just a quick bonus question why is mouseenter better then mouseover? :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.loss').mouseover(function(){             
         $('.lossOfProject', this).fadeIn();
});
```

BTW, what do you need the height for?

Comment: the loss that i am targeting is a div and i needed the height i did however found another way to get i so i just forgot to delete it:-) i will try you suggestion thanks!

Comment: why not just `$(this).fadeIn()`??

Comment: @Mario Lopez this did not work :( bother to take a look at it again? updated with HTML code too ! thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry I thought the structure was like: <div class="loss"><div class="lossOfProject"></div></div>

Answer (score 0):

You can use '$(this)' in your function to target the paragraph you are currently hovering:

```
$('.loss').mouseover(function(){
           $(this).height();
           $(this).fadeIn();
 });
```